# How do I escape the ampersand character (&) in cql?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am inserting a statement into a table that looks something like this:
`insert into db.table (field1, field2) values (1, 'eggs&cheese')`

but when i later query this error on our servers, my query returns:
`eggs\u0026cheese` instead.

Not sure whether to use `\` or `'`

If anyone can help, that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Ended up figuring this out, turns out it was a problem with gson, and all i had to do was escape html encoded characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a problem with CQL but the way your app displays the value.

For example, if the CQL column type is `text`, the unicode character is encoded as a UTF-8 string.

Using this example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE unicodechars (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    randomtext text
)
```

cqlsh displays the ampersand as expected:

```
cqlsh> SELECT * FROM unicodechars  ;

 id | randomtext
----+-------------
  1 | eggs&cheese
```